# Encrypting Passwords so devs do not have access to the key

Tags: c#, sql, encryption, password-encryption

I am writing a web framework and I am looking for a good way to Hash passwords.  I have used BCrypt and know the advantages of a Salted password using a hashing algorithm with a work factor but I have a concern.

I have worked in a few companies and there seems to be a huge turnover rate with developers.  Every place I have worked, I have had to have access to the Hash key.  It seems to me if 100's of developers have access to the key, there is a huge potential security hole.  I was trying to find a good place to hide it so that only senior management would have access but Devs could still load the projects and develop on their local machines.

One Idea I had was to create an API on the production machine so that everything had to authenticate though it meaning Devs could load the project and it would just call the service.  This just seemed like a messy way to do it.

Another idea I had would be to use the PWDCOMPARE and PWDENCRYPT in SQL.  This seems like a great solution and it is easy to implement.  What I have not been able to find is information on things like upgrading the database or replication.  If I use this method, what are the pitfalls?

I have looked in to Config encryption too to hide the key but it seems the dev would still have to have access to the key to encrypt it to the local machine.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Dont encrypt passwords - that allows them to be decrypted.  Hash them, instead.

Comment: Simplest solution for when you do need to encrypt a password (For example you are storing a password to a 3rd party service), devs don't get access to production servers, people who do have access to production servers do not get access to source code.

Comment: Your thinking is flawed in that, having 1 key is a terrible idea. triple A (AAA) security is what you want to look at. Each user should be able to be uniquley identified from their own key (otherwise you cant fill the _Accounting_ part of AAA).

Comment: As to how you encrypt keys, i agree with Plutonix... hash

Comment: I apologize.  I meant Hash.  Both Bcrypt and SQL's password functions are 1 way hashes.   I guess in the dev Database, I could use a different key as a Dev Key.  Devs have to have access to the code though.

Comment: If each user has their own key, how can they log in from multiple locations?  Wouldn't they need to store their key somewhere?

Comment: I don't really get what this "hash key" is and what it is used for, so it's quite hard to say what it means to security if someone knows it.

Comment: What do you mean with "hash key", is it the plaintext password/key itself, or is it the hash of the password/key? Do you need a retrieveable plaintext password to login to 3rd party services, or do you need only the hash to authenticate a user?